# What are the relationships between $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ in $\vec a\cdot\vec b=\vec a\cdot\vec c$ and $\vec a\times\vec b=\vec a\times\vec c$

Tags: vectors

This question is in my assignment:

> Answer the following with either an explanation, a diagram or a proof:
>
> 1. If  $\vec a\cdot\vec b=\vec a\cdot\vec c$, what is the relationship between $\vec b$ and $\vec c$?
> 2. If  $\vec a\times\vec b=\vec a\times\vec c$, what is the relationship between $\vec b$ and $\vec c$?

I've tried drawing some diagrams of different vectors, and thought about how to find a proof, but I'm coming up blank. What exactly is the relationship of the vectors $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ in these equations?

Comment: In he first case you have that $\vec{b}-\vec{c}$ is ortogonal to $\vec{a}$.

Comment: in the second case you have that $\vec{b}-\vec{c}$ is parallel to $\vec{a}$

Comment: Hmm, I see.. how would I explain, prove or draw this, though? I can't really visualize why this is.

Comment: $a\cdot b=a\cdot c \iff a\cdot (b-c)=0$ and then $a$ is orthogonal to $b-c$, the same technique apply to the other case.

Comment: How do I prove that $\vec a\cdot(\vec b-\vec c)=0$, though?

Comment: the dot product is distributive with respect to addition of the vectors in the euclidian space, that is, 

$a\cdot (b+c)=a\cdot b+a\cdot c$,

then $a\cdot b-a\cdot c=a\cdot (b-c)$

Comment: Ah, yes indeed! I get it! I can see how I prove the dot product part at least.. How does this technique apply to the cross product part, though?

Comment: I figured out how to prove it with cross product, but I'm wondering, when you say "parallel" that's equal to saying they're collinear, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** Here are useful identities for your problem. We have the following property for the inner product

> $$ a.b = ||a||\,||b|| \cos \alpha, $$

where $\alpha$ is the angle between the two vectors and for the cross product,

> $$ ||a \times b|| = ||a||\,||b||\,\sin \theta, $$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors.

Comment: I don't really know what an inner product is. I think this is a bit beyond the scope of the course I'm taking.

Comment: @Threethumb:So, where did these questions come from? However, dot product of two vectors is a scalar while the cross product of two vectors is a vector perpendicular to the plain that contains the two vectors. So, at least, you should be able to know how to perform dot and cross products of vectors.

Comment: They came from the third unit of a Canadian high school course. Yeah, it did cover cross products and dot products, but that's about it.

Comment: @Threethumb: So, if you use the identities I gave in my answer you should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Ah, yes, I figured it out now. Thank you!