# If $a\cdot b=a \cdot c$, what is the relationship between $b$ and $c$? $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all vectors.

Tags: vectors, inner-products, cross-product

So the question I have is for:

> Answer the following with either an explanation, a diagram or a proof:
>
> If $a\cdot b=a \cdot c$ , what is the relationship between $b$  and $c$? If
>   $a\times b =a\times c$ , what is the relationship between $b$  and $c$?

So $a$ is orthogonal to $(b-c)$ as if $a\cdot b=a \cdot c$, then $a\cdot b=a \cdot c= 0$, then $a\cdot(b-c) = 0$, therefore $(b-c)$ is orthogonal to $a$, but how do I express the relationship between $b$ and $c$?

Here's what else I got:

$a\cdot b = |a||b|\cos(ab)$

$a\cdot c = |a||c|cos(ac)$

$|a||b|\cos(ab) -  |a||c|\cos(ac) = 0$

$|a|(|b| \cos(ab) - |c|\cos(ac)) = 0$

$|b| = |c|\cos(ac) / \cos(ab)$

I'm not sure what I'm missing for the dot product question. For the cross product question, which properties would be used to solve it?

Comment: Do you know an interpretation of these products in terms of components?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the relationships between $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ in $\vec a\cdot\vec b=\vec a\cdot\vec c$ and $\vec a\times\vec b=\vec a\times\vec c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649214/what-are-the-relationships-between-vec-b-and-vec-c-in-vec-a-cdot-vec-b)

Comment: a . b = a1b1 + a2b2 + a3b3

Comment: a . b = a1b1 + a2b2 + a3b3, a.c = a1c1 + a2c2 + a3c3

Comment: a1b1 + a2b2 + a3b3 =  a1c1 + a2c2 + a3c3

Comment: Would that be useful though? I saw that duplicate, it got the same answer that I got that a is orthogonal to (b-c), but not what the relationship between b/c is?